# Implement Parcelable for a List<Map<String, String>>

Tags: android

I want to pass a `List<Map<String, String>>` to another Activity. How to implement Parcelable for it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141944/android-pass-listgeopoint-to-another-activity

Comment: Wouldn't you just add your List to the intent (with putExtra()) when you call your activity

Comment: @Gaara: It doesn't fit my needs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400564/android-parcelable-retailerorderactivity-java-return-null/7400675#7400675

Comment: the simplest way this make it "public static"

Comment: Can anybody give me some code? It's too hard to implement. It is absolutely not like to the GeoPoint sample above.

Comment: Can't you use  `putExtra (String name, Serializable value)` ?

Comment: @Gubbel: Is List<Map<String, String>> serialized? I can't find out any sample on SO.

Comment: do you think you can store it in database and retuen a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend `Map` and implement `Parcelable` for it. When writing to parcel, you could write elements count as a first `int`, then iterate over entries and add them one after another like:

```
destParcelable.writeInt(size());
for (final Entry<String, String> entry : getEntries()) {
  destParcelable.writeString(entry.getKey());
  destParcelable.writeString(entry.getValue());
}
```

When reading from parcel just read the first `int` (that will be your entries count) and start a loop reading key and values one by one:

```
final int size = srcParcelable.readInt();
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
  put(srcParcelable.readString(), srcParcelable.readString());
}
```

And I believe there is a method to add list of parcelables to bundle, and since your map is a parcelable now it won't be any problems.

Answer (score 2):

When possible, try to use `Bundle` instead `Map`. In your case, `List<Map<String, String>>` a `Bundle` can replace very well.

More info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:
1. Make a constructor of activity where you want to pass this list.

```
public Class CalledActivity extends Activity{

List<Map<String, String>> list;
public calledActivity(List<Map<String, String>> list){
this.list=list;
}
}
```

2. Call this constructor from the activity, you want to pass the list from.

See this question for reference. [android activity class constructor working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725530/android-activity-class-constructor-working)